# A single Shopify store for US and Europe, is it possible?

Tags: shopify

I'm new to Shopify and I'm looking for some guidance.

I have a customer who has a warehouse in the US and a warehouse in Europe. They have a Shopify store for US customers, with a shipping from address set to the warehouse in the US.

They do not have a store for European customers.

What they would like to do, which I'm not sure is possible... Is keep the current US store, and add the ability to ship to Europe. This would require adding prices in Euros, for each product, and adding a second Shipping from address, which does not seem to be an option.

Does anyone have any experience with this, and can provide some guidance on any of these points?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd agree with what David said. It is easier and less-tax-hassle free two maintain the store on two domains.

But I can see why you require a multi-currency store. Fortunately, Shopify does have provision to at least display the product prices and offer a toggle switch for the users.

Refer to the following Shopify docs:

1. [Show multiple currencies in a drop-down list on your storefront](https://docs.shopify.com/manual/configuration/store-customization/currencies-and-translations/currencies/how-to-show-multiple-currencies)
2. [Add a button to your online store to enable toggling between two currencies](https://docs.shopify.com/manual/configuration/store-customization/currencies-and-translations/currencies/how-to-toggle-between-two-currencies)

Answer (score 1):

To do that, you would have to show prices in Euros, but all money would be collected as USD. Not ideal. Plus EU usually has taxes in, US, not. Shipping is easy in that you can control where things get dropshipped from.

It is simpler to just open two shops. One for Euroland, and one for the US Shops are cheap compared to the sweat you'll put in trying to make one store do it all.